# jOOQ "IN" Predicate with Degree N Tuples

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I need a `WHERE` clause to check tuples `IN` a list: `(field1, field2) in (('1', 1), ('2', 2), ('3', 3))`. This is valid SQL in Postgres.

Dialect: `POSTGRES`

jOOQ Version: `3.9.6`

What is the correct jOOQ syntax for this case?

jOOQ 3.9 documentation implies this is possible, but their example only gives degree 1: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/

This code gives an approximation of what I'm looking for, but I can't get the right type/data for `referenceOrderIdLineNumbers` nor can I get the right SQL generated by jOOQ.

```
Collection<Row2<String, Integer>> referenceOrderIdLineNumbers = ...
List<Object[]> rows = dsl.select(... , field("count(TABLE3)", Integer.class )
  .from(Tables.TABLE1)
  .join(Tables.TABLE2).on(Tables.TABLE2.PK1.eq(Tables.TABLE1.PK1))
  .join(Tables.TABLE3).on(Tables.TABLE3.PK2.eq(Tables.TABLE2.PK2))
  .where(
    row(Tables.TABLE1.FIELD1, Tables.TABLE2.FIELD2) // <-- what to 
    .in(referenceOrderIdLineNumbers)                // <-- do here??
  )
  .groupBy(...)
  .fetch();
```

Comment: What version of PG dose you use ? I just test the "(field1, field2) in (('1', 1), ('2', 2))" expression in PG, it works.

Comment: You're using `List rows` as an assignment target, a raw type. Once you have a single raw type in your expression, all generics break in Java. This means you might be calling a wrong overload of your `in()` method, by accident. Of course, it would help if you provide a bit more information about your query that helps reproduce the problem you're getting, in particular the SQL that is currently being generated, the types of `TABLE1.FIELD1`, etc. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: @LukasEder: I disambiguated the `rows` type, but that generic is not what causes the issue (I can leave out the variable assignment entirely). This is more a question about the correct syntax--that's why I linked to the documentation--since a full REPREX would be mostly extraneous information in the form of generated code. The `TABLE` objects are trivial and would detract from the question.

Comment: @JJZabkar: As you wish :) This feature works in all our integration tests, so I don't know how else to help you, if I can't reproduce it. Of course, I still think you could post the SQL that *is* being generated by your code to see why it deviates from what you're expecting. From what I'm seeing, your API usage is correct.

Comment: @LukasEder (re: generated SQL) ah! Great call. Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working as intended for me. You might try having jOOQ log the SQL its generating for you and try running said SQL against your database directly.

References:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-execution/logging/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/

```
Collection<Row2<String, Integer>> field1Field2Collection = new LinkedList<>();
field1Field2Collection.add(row("1", 1));
field1Field2Collection.add(row("2", 2));
field1Field2Collection.add(row("3", 3));

Result<Record2<String, Integer>> field1Field2Results = dsl
        .select(Tables.TABLE1.FIELD1, Tables.TABLE2.FIELD2)
        .from(Tables.TABLE1)
        .join(Tables.TABLE2).on(Tables.TABLE2.PK1.eq(Tables.TABLE1.PK1))
        .where(row(Tables.TABLE1.FIELD1, Tables.TABLE2.FIELD2).in(field1Field2Collection))
        .fetch();
```